# What Are the Meaning of the Terms in a 3D Plane Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, plane-geometry

The question is the following:

> The equation $3x+5y+7z=15$ can be rewritten as $z = \frac{15}{7} - \frac{3}{7}x-\frac{5}{7}y$. What are the meanings of the three fractions that appear in this equation?

I know that $\frac{15}{7}$ is the intersection of the plane on the $z$-axis. However, is $-\frac{3}{7}$ the slope on the $x$-axis and $-\frac{5}{7}$ on the $y$-axis? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That's basically it. If you increase the $x$ coordinate by $1$, you will increase the $z$ coordinate by $-\frac 37$ (assuming you stay on the plane of course). Edit: I'm not sure whether this has a proper name though.

Comment: Thank you so much!